# How I Detect if a NSUrlSession exist iOS

Tags: ios, nsurlsession

I have a TableView which pushes a viewController. This viewController creates a `NSURLSession` to download in a separate process. but can I detect if the session exists in the event that the user re-enters the viewController before the process is finished?

```
NSString *name= [NSString stringWithString:[self.myObject objectForKey:@"title"]];
self.conf = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:name];
self.backgroundDownloadSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:self.conf
                                                                   delegate:self
                                                              delegateQueue:self.delegateQueue
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
if (!self.backgroundDownloadSession) {
  // ...
}
```

If you are suggesting that you are also recreating whatever `self` is, then consider making your `NSURLSession` owned by a different object that will persist longer (or make it static).

Answer (score 0):

You can always check if `self.backgroundDownloadSession` is not nil, 
but if you want to make sure it is still in process even if your controller is not alive, 
I would make it a property of a singelton class,so instead of `self.backgroundDownloadSession` 
something like: `[AppManager sharedInstance].backgroundDownloadSession`
when  AppManager is a singleton.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the typical answers are singletons or static variable (e.g., with the `dispatch_once` pattern) or some property of some class that you know is instantiated only once (e.g. your app delegate). The process is simply "if I have not yet instantiated session, do so; if I have instantiated it, get reference to that existing instance".

Having said that, it's worth noting that in the case of `NSURLSession`, you have to handle this process not only as you submit new requests in your view controller, but also in your app delegate where you respond to `handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession` (e.g. where you capture the completion handler that you call, for example, in `URLSessionDidFinishEventsForBackgroundURLSession`).